# Remove reply url using Azure cli

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to remove a specific reply url from my Redirect URIs:

```
az ad app update --id *** --remove replyUrls removethisurl
```

If I run this code I get the message:

> ERROR: invalid syntax: --remove property.list  OR --remove propertyToRemove

If I run this code:

```
az ad app update --id *** --remove replyUrls 1
```

This script works but there doesn't seem to be any change in the reply urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This script works but there doesn't seem to be any change in the reply
>   urls.

I think your script should work if it executes without any error. The command `az ad app update --id *** --remove replyUrls 1` actually removes the **second** `replyUrls` of your App registrations. The `replyUrls` is an array beginning from index 0 instead of 1.

Hmm, I assume you have more than one replyUrls before running that script, and the second command works to remove the second one(index=1), now you can still see the first one(index=0). That's why there doesn't seem to be any change in the reply urls. Also, another possibility is that even when we executes the command successfully locally, we need to refresh the web portal to see the change! (As for me, `az ad app show --id` can immediately see the changes, but the web portal needs some seconds and a refresh.)

**My test steps:**

If the command **not** works, it will throw error like `index 1 doesn't exist on replyUrls`.

[image]

In my opinion, your script worked. It's just we did't notice that well :)

**To confirm that:**

You can run `az ad app show --id xxx` command to get details of your App registrations. You can see something like this in response:

[image]

If your command(`az ad app update --id *** --remove replyUrls 1`) works, then you will find only one(two originally) replyUrls when you run the `az ad app show --id xxx` again.

(To see the change in web portal, we need to refresh it after seconds)

Hope all above helps to resolve your puzzle :)

**Update:**

Make sure you're using the latest version 2.2.0 of Azure CLI. Download link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: It's dumb that even after years of working you can miss stuff  like > `actually removes the second replyUrls`. This was in fact the case :). Also thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help :)